# Good Source of Difficult Problems for 9th Grade Integrated Math Student (US curriculum)

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I've got a student in 9th grade under an integrated math curriculum who is doing very well. I want to begin introducing them to more difficult problems and I was wondering if there is a good source for such problems out there.

I know Geometry For Fun and Challenge is a good text, but these new curricula introduced after the common core are integrated, meaning they try to have more word problems where algebra and geometry are no longer separated, and I'm hoping - even though this change is very recent, to find problem sets specifically for integrated math students.

Sources/Textbooks with problem sets for Geometry or Algebra are welcome too, as long as they are targeted to 9th graders.

Any ideas?

(PS This might not be the best place for this question, perhaps there's a more specific forum for junior high and high school educators)

EDIT: 'Integrated Math' being the umbrella term for any high school math sequence that deviates from the old American standard of Algebra 1 - Geometry - Algebra 2 and replaces it with, well, more integrated curricula mixing Algebra and Geometry.

Comment: In response to the postscript, there is a [math educators SE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) (but it's still in beta so my guess is that you'll get more visibility here).

Comment: What is "integrated math"? Do people really still believe we all are in the same country or even county?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'll edit the post to make it clear this is for a US student.